# Combine onlick and onmouseover in the same function

Tags: javascript, onclick, onmouseover, onhover

I want to combine onclick and onmouseover in the same line.

I have

```
if (var) {
        var.onclick = function() {
//          do something
}
```

I want to add

```
if (var) {
            var.onclick || var.onmouseover= function() {
    //          do something
    }
```

Something like that

Comment: `var myFunc = function(e) {}; var.onclick = var.onmouseover = myFunc;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the events can be stored in an array which can be iterate & use `addEventListener` to add attache the event with the element

```js
var x = document.getElementById("test")

if (x) {
  ['click', 'mouseover'].forEach(function(item) {
    x.addEventListener(item, function(event) {
      console.log(event.type)
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<button id="test">Test Button</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way. But also change your variable name

```
el.onclick = el.onmouseover = function() {

}
```

`el.onmouseover` will refer to a function and the `el.onmouseover = function()` will return the function reference, which also will be assigned to the `el.onclick`.

**Example**

```js
let a;
let b;

a = b = function() {
  console.log('Test');
};

a();
b();

console.log(a === b);
```